# Change word under cursor from inside a vim function

Tags: function, vim

I want to write a function, which increases/decreases the size of a LaTeX text. E.g., when the cursor is above the word *\footnotesize* I want to call `Tex_ChangeSize(-1)` to change it to *\small* and `Tex_ChangeSize(1)` to change it to *\normalsize*.

What I have is the following:

```
function! Tex_ChangeSize(direction)
    let sizes = ["tiny", "scriptsize", "footnotesize", "small", "normalsize", "large", "Large", "LARGE", "huge", "Huge"]
    let cursize = index(sizes,expand("<cword>"))
    if cursize != -1
        "FIXME: replace current word under cursor with the following
        echo sizes[cursize + a:direction]
    endif
endfunction
imap <C-h> <C-o>:call Tex_ChangeSize(-1)<Enter>
imap <C-g> <C-o>:call Tex_ChangeSize(1)<Enter>
```

What I don't know is, how to replace the word under cursor (see FIXME).
To be more precise: Is there a better way than parsing `getline(line('.'))` and setting it back with `setline()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getline+setline is one the neater choice as it won't mess any register (neither `@"` nor `@/`), however finding the limits of a current word is a bit tricky in an utf-8 world where tab characters (\t) can also be used. (`col('.')` + `match()` will do it ; see https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/vim-tip-swap-word.vim for examples)

You can also have a nnoremapping that does a simple `cw<c-r>=<sid>ChangeSize(1)<cr>` with `s:ChangeSize()` that tests `@"` to see which symbol is next in order to return it -- not messing `@"` is simple though in this case.

You can also play with `:exe 'normal! "_cw'.new_word` from within the function if you'd rather not have it return anyting.